# -KeyExportPolicy Exportable` did not work Export-PfxCertificate : Cannot export non-exportable private key

Tags: windows, powershell, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I launched PowerShell with administrator privileges on Windows 11 and executed the following code to create a .pfx file. However, an error occurred, and I couldn't create the .pfx file.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -KeyExportPolicy Exportable  -KeySpec KeyExchange -Type Custom -Subject "CN=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", "2.5.29.19={text}")

Set-Location Cert:\CurrentUser\My
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject, Thumbprint

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxx" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\CurrentUser\My\xxxx-FilePath "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\cert.pfx" -Password $password
```

The error message is as follows.

```
Export-PfxCertificate : Export-PfxCertificate : Cannot export non-exportable private key
Location of occurrence: Line: 1, Character: 1

+ Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\CurrentUser\My\xxxxx...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-PfxCertificate], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ExportPfxCer
   tificate
```

Using `-KeyExportPolicy Exportable` did not work.

What else could I try?
I recently purchased a new PC. On my previous PC, I was able to generate the .pfx file correctly, but I don't exactly remember how I did it.